# Selenium WebDriver C# - difficulty switching from iFrame back to MainPage headings

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, automated-tests

Be kind, this is my 2nd mionth of using selenium and C#......

I am testing web-pages in IE and am able to switch between modal popups/frames/etc. I am having trouble though after closing the current page I am on (which navigates me back to my start point), selecting the element for another main heading on the page?

So this is the start, that works correctly (Before you ask, it is web-based hotels management software):

```
        // Navigate to and logon to page
        this.Login();

        // Selects the reservations main heading
        **this.ClickElementByID("rpt_TopMenu_ctl06_lbtn_MenuItem");** //This is a "MainMenu" item in question

        // Selects the reservations sub-heading
        this.ClickElementByID("x:1675617787.4:adr:0.2");

        // Switch to main page frame
        this.TargetFrame("MainFrame");

        // Selects 'create new reservation'
        this.ClickElementByID("wbtn_CreateIndividualReservation");

        //// Set text for title
        this.EnterTextByID("tc_tp_Main_rpt_Guests_ctl00_winp_Title", "Mr");

        //// Set text for firstname
        this.EnterTextByID("tc_tp_Main_rpt_Guests_ctl00_winp_Forename", "A");

        // Set text for lastname
        this.EnterTextByID("tc_tp_Main_rpt_Guests_ctl00_winp_Surname", "ABCDEFG");
```

It continues to input data until I hit close. My assumption is that it is still registering me as on iFrame 'MainFrame'. But without any other frame ID's I have no idea of how to switch back to an unfocuased page-view. The Frame I am in is below the element heading I am trying to select (seperate).

The heading does have a FormID, but not to sure how to switch focus to this?.....Help...

Any criticism would be great as I am still learning and dont want to develop bad habits (ps, im self-tought so probably a few bad habits in there already).

-Colin

Comment: Forgot to add, I am using Selenium Webdriver (Not IDE, I cant get used to IDE)....

Comment: So somewhere in your code (which you've wrapped in your own methods and declined to share), you're doing a `driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frameName)`, right? And after completing your work in the frame, you want to exit back out to the top-level frame? Or do you need to navigate to a sibling frame? Or am I missing something altogether? From your description, I'm not able to visualize the frame structure, and where you're trying to go.

Comment: Cheers Jim, I will add my methods for you to have a look at as soon as I get in. Yeah, just read the start of my explanation (a bit higgledy piggledy...). To summarise, I have selected a mainHeading; selected a sub heading (which loads further selectables on the MainFrame); switch to main frame to make my selections. After this I would like to select another mainHeading and am struggling to select elements. I have tried many methods. Is there a way of un-focusing on the frame I have switched to? This is the only solution I can think of

Comment: Have you tried `driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent()`? That puts the focus back on the top-level frame.

Comment: The last 3 methods are the ones in question @JimEvans .... <br/>  <code> /// <summary>
        /// Switches to a new frame
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="frameId"></param>
        protected void TargetFrame(string frameId)
        {
            mWebDriver.SwitchTo().Frame(frameId);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Swithces to a new window
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="windowId"></param>
        protected void TargetWindow(string windowId)
        {
            mWebDriver.SwitchTo().Window(windowId);
        }    </br>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With WebDriver in C#, you can get the current frame element like this:

```
WebElement el = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return window.frameElement");
```

You should get and store this element before switching to MainFrame, so that you can then switch back as needed.

Comment: Cheers Matt, I'll give this a go! Cheers!